# How can I make a GAN that uses inputs of lower res images to output high res images?

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network

I want to know if there is a way to use low res images to produce high res images using a GAN.

Comment: They are called [SRGAN](https://paperswithcode.com/method/srgan).

Comment: I want to make a high res image from a batch of low res images, not make a singular picture higher res.

Comment: That's not what you asked in the title or in your question.